# Does C# have generic constructors?

Tags: c#, generics, constructor

Java has generic constructors; i.e., a constructor can specify type parameters and it can be called parameterized.

In java, it looks like this:

```
class Foo{
    <T> Foo(T t){...}
}
```

Now I can call it this way:

```
new <String>Foo("xyz");
```

Does C# have a similar feature? If not, then what would be the best way to mimic such feature? Maybe a generic factory method?

Please note that I am not talking about generic classes! Generic constructors are something different.

Comment: Can you provide a real-world example of a problem solved by a hypothetical generic constructor but not by a generic class ? I can't think of any

Comment: @clto: See the answer in the other question; they are! They do not even exist in C#!

Comment: How are generic classes different from generic constructors? If you use the generic parameter in any way it's part of the class. So even if you mimic the behavior with a generic factory method: `` Foo Create<T>(T t)`` you won't be able to introduce the generic parameter to the class without it having it as well.

Comment: @Alex: No, not really. But Java has them :P.

Comment: @Zache: A generic constructor has the type parameter only during its invocation. The created object is *NOT* generic.

Comment: @gexicide Well, I guess no Java-class is truly generic because of Type Erasure. Could you provide an implementation of using a generic constructor where using a generic class would be bad?

Comment: @Zache: I can't think of a sane example right now. But in general: Whenever you need the generic parameter only during initialization of a class, then making the whole class generic would be an overkill.

Comment: @Zache Using a generic class would be bad any time you want two different constructor invocations (with different type arguments) to return the same class, for example because which call is made depends on a runtime variable value.

Comment: @gexicide BTW, your generic factory method idea sounds good to me, and is probably what I'd do.

Comment: I never thought about generic constructors, but my guess is it's bad design. I would really like an answer to this question. Also, the syntax is ambiguous. If you have 2 classes, Foo<T> and Foo with a generic constructor, what does 'new Foo<string>()' instantiate?